# how to call boost libraries on appveyor, how to set environment variable to run boost test successfully?

Tags: appveyor

I want to run boost test in appveyor. My code can built successfully without boost test. When I run boost test, it has compile error.

```
Build started
2
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/Gaussma/StaticLibrary.git c:\projects\myproject
3
git checkout -qf 857f43f706d59e6ed74d7af6771d102850e615a0
4
msbuild "c:\projects\myproject\StaticLibrary.sln" /verbosity:minimal /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"
5
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
7
8
  LinkedListcpp.cpp
9
  MathFuncsLib.cpp
10
  Generating Code...
11
  MathFuncsLib.vcxproj -> c:\projects\myproject\x64\Debug\MathFuncsLib.lib
12
  boostTest_LinkedList.cpp
13
c:\projects\myproject\myexecrefslib\boosttest_linkedlist.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp': No such file or directory [c:\projects\myproject\MyExecRefsLib\MyExecRefsLib.vcxproj]
```

Cleary, the appveyor can not find the boost library.
Locally, I am using Visual Studio 2017 and boost library 1_68_0 to generate the MyExecRefsLib.vcxproj file.

I search on the stackoverflow and find others implement the .yml file in this way.

```
environment:
  BOOST_ROOT: C:\Libraries\boost_1_59_0
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: C:\Libraries\boost_1_59_0\lib64-msvc-14.0
```

I update it correspondingly for boost_1_67_0 since I am using Visual Studio 2017 in appveyor and boost already installed in appveyor Virtual Machine.
https://www.appveyor.com/docs/windows-images-software/#boost

```
environment:
  BOOST_ROOT: C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0\lib64-msvc-14.1
```

I do not have .yml file , I set those two the environmental variables manually in the project's setting in appveyor.

I am wondering what is the correction setting for those two environment variables to run boost test? Current setting has compile error.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Wenn posting a question, above the edit window is are icons that help you format your code. Please make sure you **at least** know how to format blocks of code (select + Ctrl+K). You also tagged this [tag:yaml] and although YAML is involved, this is not a correct tag (hover above a tag to see how it should be used). Readable questions and appropriate tags give you higher chance of getting an applicable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Acutually, this is very easy question. We should make the build environment are same between my local machine and appveyor.

In appveyor : 
   environment:
  BOOST_ROOT: C:\Libraries\boost_1_64_0
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: C:\Libraries\boost_1_64_0\lib64-msvc-14.1

In Visual Studio :

Project-> Properties-> C/C++ ->General -> Additional Include Directories : C:\Libraries\boost_1_64_0

Project-> Properties->Linker -> Additional Library Dependencies :  C:\Libraries\boost_1_64_0\lib64-msvc-14.1

Just move the boost_1_64_0 in the Libraries and change the library from stage_x8\lib  to lib64-msvc-14.1 is OK.